# TableViewCell is nil

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 2 tableviews in my ViewController. And I am switching between the 2 based on a flag.

When i load the viewcontroller, the comment table view is loaded but for some reason the cellComment is turning up nil.
I have registered the tableview class and have also set the Identifier in the storyboard but the dequeue is not working

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(currentSelectionNews)
    {
        CMLTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    UITableViewCell *cellComment = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    // cellComment in nil
    [self configureCommentCell:cellComment atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cellComment;
}
```

The other tableview loads fine. I created that first in the storyboard.

Comment: Don't register cell inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: You should only register the class if you made the cell (with its subviews) in code. If you made it in a xib then your should register the nib. If you made it in a storyboard, then don't register anything.

Comment: Are you using Storyboards and prototype cells or XIBs? If you are using Storyboards and Prototype cells then you do not need the call to `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` nor the `if (cellComment == nil) {...}` block recommended below.

Comment: I am using storyboard and prototype cell - you are right.. i removed the register call .. and it works fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` only works if you have already created a cell that is waiting to be recycled. Try this:

```
UITableViewCell *cellComment = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if(cellComment == nil){
    cellComment = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```

Comment: Your first statement is not correct. If the cell was made in a storyboard (as the OP says he is), then dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: will return a valid cell. It will create it if it needs to from the storyboard definition, or get one from the recycle queue. There's no need for the if (cell==nil) clause.